# How can I check what happened to a SWIFT transfer with a party that is neither the originator financial institution nor the beneficiary institution?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, international-transfer, france, swift

I have an account at a financial institution in France and I have an account at a financial institution in the US. I asked my financial institution in France to do a SWIFT transfer from my account with them to my account in the US. A few hours after, my financial institution in France said that my financial institution in the US rejected the SWIFT transfer, and my financial institution in the US said they never received any SWIFT transfer. A few days after, their claims haven't changed. I'll get my money back, but it may take up to 20 working days according to my financial institution in France.

I have the UETR (Unique End-to-end Transaction Reference, which is a string of 36 unique characters present in all payment instruction messages carried over Swift). How can I check what happened to that SWIFT transfer with another party?

---

https://tipalti.com/swift-payments/ mentions:

> If your bank is a member of SWIFT, they can check on the status of a payment at any given time of day.

But it doesn't specify whether only the financial institution who sent SWIFT transfer may check its status.

Comment: Obviously… you **ask them**.

Comment: @RonJohn you're **overestimating**... their customer support.

Comment: If you want to know why Big Bank of Country rejected a transaction, the obvious solution is to **ask Big Bank of County**.  Only after that fails do you go to Plan B.

Comment: @RonJohn "my financial institution in the US said they never received any SWIFT transfer." so we're doing plan B now.

Comment: That then is a different question, isn’t it?

Comment: @RonJohn no the question is "How can I check what happened to a SWIFT transfer with a party that is neither the originator financial institution nor the beneficiary institution?" this is plan B.

Comment: I believe only the sending institution can trace the transfer, but they may not want to or care enough to be bothered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have read and been told by a few people that given some UETR (Unique End-to-end Transaction Reference), only the originator financial institution can check the status of a SWIFT transfer.

---

- Source 1: Charles Schwab customer service.
- Source 2: [littleadv](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998/littleadv)'s [comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/155086/how-can-i-check-what-happened-to-a-swift-transfer-with-a-party-that-is-neither-t#comment317061_155086) (they mentioned they aren't 100% sure. The comment got 2 upvotes.)
- Source 3: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vosfinances/comments/10wkd8i/comment_puisje_v%C3%A9rifier_ce_quil_est_advenu_dun/j7os692/)